# Interactive filtering histogram widget with cartoJS

Tags: carto, carto-js, cartogram

I would like an interactive filtering histogram widget like this one https://public.carto.com/builder/0c982e6d-b254-4e2b-86ed-e0f097f519c2/embed (the population density histogram widgets on right bottom of screen). When you click or select histogram's bars data are filtered on map.

I know how to do this with cartoDB;
https://carto.com/help/tutorials/improve-the-message-of-your-map-through-styling/#leverage-autostyling
What I want is to make 1 with cartoJS.

As cartoJS solution, I found this histogram widget : https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/examples/#example-viewport-histogram-widget
but the widget is not interactive.
Clicking on histogram's bars does not filter the spots on the map.

Does anyone know how I could make an interactive filtering histogram widget with cartoJS ?

---

I built this coloured Airship Histogram widget : http://softpeople.fr/DEMO/cartoDB2/4.html

This time I made Histogram coloured but still I can't find a way to apply filtering on data map by selected histogram's bars.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score -3):

Answers can be found here :

Widget interactivity :
https://carto.com/developers/airship/examples/#example-as-histogram-events
https://github.com/jahow/ol-airship-bridge

Widget coloured bars :
https://github.com/CartoDB/airship/pull/425/commits/c4eb2a3797c89b1e6eb1c9848a1f2135c0c49916